# AWS Amplify Auth.confirmSignIn doesnt sign in

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have a component that is wrapped with this component

```
export default function RequireAuth({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
 const location = useLocation();
  const { route } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.route]);
  console.log(route);
  if (route !== 'authenticated') {
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  }
  return children;
}
```

When a MFA enabled user tries to log in and the user enters the code and this function fires

```
      Auth.confirmSignIn(awsUser, userCode, challenge).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    setLoading(false);
    navigate('/');
  });
```

It navigates to the landing page however is redirected back to login page because the route != authenticated

Why is the confirmSignIn not successfully logging in? There are no errors being thrown from this function either its the log is just the CognitoUser object